# ¿Como concatenar un string en un array char?

Tags: c++, linux

Tengo un problema al intentar añadir un string a un array char, la consola me da error de código

Este es mi código:

```
std::string text1 = "hello";
std::string text2 = "world";

const char *texto[] = {
    "Texto1: " std::text1,
    "Texto2: " std::text2
}
```

El error que me muestra es este: `expected '}'` y `to match '}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complicas las cosas más de la cuenta, [String](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) posee una función llamada [c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/), la cual devuelve el un puntero constante char a la cadena `const char *`, tu código perfectamente podría ser el siguiente:

```
std::string text1 = "Texto1: ";
text1.append("hello");
std::string text2 = "Texto2: ";
text2.append("world");

const char *texto[] = {
    text1.c_str(), 
    text2.c_str()
}; //<== Este punto y coma
```

Y tu error es porque falta un punto y coma al final de la declaración del array.

---

## EDITADO 1

Quiero aclarar algo porque fui muy corto, la manera en que te lo plantee, funciona, hace específicamente lo que querías y punto, pero debes tener algo en cuenta, la función [c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) devuelve un puntero a la matrix de datos actual, si después del código que te plantee, llegases a modificar alguno de tus dos `string`, la matrix `texto[]` quedaría apuntando a nada, porque *no se le realizo una copia, se le paso fue el apuntador*, para evitar esto, se necesita dar memoria a la matrix y realizar una copia de los `string`, esté código sirve:

> este código es sacado del codigo de ejemplo de la documentación de
>   [c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) y modificado para que se ajuste a tu caso particular

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string text1 = "Texto1: ";
  text1.append("hello");
  std::string text2 = "Texto2: ";
  text2.append("world");

  char **texto = new char *[2];
  texto[0] = new char[text1.length() + 1];
  texto[1] = new char[text2.length() + 1];

  //Función de copia para cadenas C 
  std::strcpy (texto[0], text1.c_str());
  std::strcpy (texto[1], text2.c_str());    

  std::cout << texto[0] << "\n";
  std::cout << texto[1] << std::endl;

  //Eliminar la memoria dinamica
  delete[] texto[0];
  delete[] texto[1];
  delete[] texto;
  return 0;
}
```

como notaras, toco dar memoria dinámica a la matrix, para realizarle la copia, ahí ya tendrías una copia, ahora, vuelvo y digo, debes tener alguna razón para querer utilizar una matrix `const char *` que se me ocurren bastante, pero si no, ¿para qué?, si no posee una razón, utiliza `std::vector<std::string>` de la cabecera `<vector>` y te evitas muchos problemas.

Comment: Esto es completa y absolutamente erroneo.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster si es asi, ¿En qué?, para no cometer el mismo error en un futuro y no dar mala información.

Comment: No es erróneo pero sí peligroso. `c_str()` te devuelve el puntero a la memoria interna del `string`. Si modificas el `string` o se invoca su destructor puedes acabar con un puntero no válido y el programa comportarse de forma errónea.

Comment: Yo he usado memoria dinamica en mi solución no porque sea fan de la misma sino porque es necesario para que evitar punteros no válidos

Comment: Nunca te quedes con un puntero de `c_str`. Ese puntero es de usar y tirar

Comment: si, ya lo había notado, actualice la respuesta.

Comment: @Mario piden un array de char y ofreces un array de punteros a char, guardas en el array de punteros a char punteros temporales, eferion dice que no es erróneo. Yo digo que cualquier código propenso a errores lo es.

Comment: Lo intente de esa forma y ahora me da otro tipo de errores de strcpy

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char cad[] = "Concatenando ";
    char cad2[] = " una cadena con otra";
    char cad3[100];

    strcpy(cad3, cad); //cad 3 = 'Concatenando '
    strcat(cad3, cad2); //cad 3 = 'Concatenando una cadena con otra'

    cout<<cad3<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`strcpy()` Sirve para copiar la cadena cadena2 dentro de cadena1 . Devuelve el valor de cadena1.

`strcat()` Permite añadir un bloque de memoria a otro.

Las declaraciones de dichas funciones, se encuentra en el archivo de cabecera `string.h`. Por tanto, para poder usar dicha función en un programa, hay que escribir:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Espero te sea util.

Answer (score 1):

> El error que me muestra es este: expected '}' y to match '}'

Esos errores te aparecen porque la construcción o es correcta por dos motivos:

- `std::text1` **no existe**. Tu tienes una variable `text1`... pero **no está declarada** en el espacio de nombres `std`.
- `char*` **no** dispone de un constructor que recoja una cadena de tipo `char` y un `std::string`. Si quieres hacer eso tienes que programar tu una función que haga esa operación. Como verás más adelante la operación no es trivial del todo.
- No has puesto un operador entre la cadena de tipo `char` y `text1`... el compilador dificilmente va a saber qué pretendes hacer con eso (tu quieres concatenarlo, pero el compilador no es adivino).

Lo más sencillo es usar un array de `string`:

```
std::string const texto[] = {
    {"Texto1: "  + text1},
    {"Texto2: "  + text2}
};
```

Aunque para esto es preferible usar `std::array`:

```
std::array<2, std::string> texto = {
    {"Texto1: "  + text1},
    {"Texto2: "  + text2}
};
```

No obstante, si tienes que usar por fuerza un array de `char`, entonces tendrás que copiar a mano el texto, ya que el contenido del mismo solo lo conoces durante la ejecución. Una posibilidad es usar lambdas (C++11):

```
auto lambda = [](int n, std::string const& text)
{
    std::string result = "Texto" + std::to_string(n) + ": " + text;

    auto ptr = new char[result.size()];
    std::copy(result.begin(),result.end(),ptr);
    return ptr;
};

char const* texto[] = {
    lambda(1, text1),
    lambda(2, text2)
};
```

Lo que hace la lambda es generar el resultado final y copiarlo en un puntero de tipo `char`. Por supuesto luego hay que acordarse de limpiar la memoria dinámica:

```
for( int i=0; i<2; ++i )
  delete[] texto[i];
```

Si no puedes (o no te dejan) usar lambdas, puedes reemplazarla facilmente por una función independiente:

```
char* lambda(int n, std::string const& text)
{
    std::string result = "Texto" + std::to_string(n) + ": " + text;

    auto ptr = new char[result.size()];
    std::copy(result.begin(),result.end(),ptr);
    return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> El error que me muestra es este: `expected '}'` y `to match '}'`

Lo raro es que el compilador no haya implosionado llevándose por delante tu vecindario. El código que has escrito no tiene ningún sentido en C++.

La manera de inicializar una formación<sup>1</sup> de `char` es escribiendo un [literal de texto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) tras el operador de asignación:

```
char formacion[] = "Literal de texto";
```

El compilador se encargará de calcular el tamaño de la formación<sup>1</sup> incluyendo el [finalizador de cadena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), como puedes ver las llaves son opcionales, pero podrías haberlas usado:

```
char formacion[] = {"Literal de texto"};
```

Tú has escrito en tu código un literal de cadena, seguido de un símbolo que no existe:

```
           vvvvvvvvvv <--- text1 NO EXISTE dentro del espacio de nombres std
"Texto1: " std::text1,
~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Literal de cadena
```

No hay manera de hacer directamente lo que quieres, para empezar las formaciones<sup>1</sup> necesitan conocer su tamaño en tiempo de compilación a no ser que sean creadas con tamaño dinámico:

```
std::string text1 = "hello";
std::string text2 = "world";

const char *texto = new char[text1.size() + text2.size()]{};
```

Una vez creada con el tamaño requerido, puedes hacer la [copia](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
auto posicion = std::copy(text1.begin(), text1.end(), texto);
std::copy(text2.begin(), text2.end(), posicion);
```

No olvides liberar la memoria cuando ya no la uses:

```
delete[] texto;
```

#### Propuesta.

Sinceramente, te estás complicando la vida, olvida la formación<sup>1</sup> y usa otro `std::string`:

```
std::string text1 = "hello";
std::string text2 = "world";
std::string texto = text1 + text2;
```

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Date cuenta que está creando un array que mezcla el contenido del string con un literal...

Comment: Darse cuenta de eso es inferir mucho de un código que no tiene ni pies ni cabeza.